# How to logout from facebook without refreshing the page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Iam working with facebook integration.Here I have written logout code which goes to login state after successful logout.But Iam facing problem in logout state.Logout works only when Iam refreshing the page so that after refreshing only it shows logout successful and goes to login state.Without refreshing the page how can I logout from facebook and change to login state?
Here is my code:

```js
var app = angular.module("logApp", [])
    .controller("logCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $state, $window) {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: "214238962389773",
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true
            });
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
                    FB.logout(function (response) {
                        $window.location.reload();
                        //                        FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');
                        /** Afer logout, Refresh the Page **/
                        console.log('Logout Successfully.');
                        document.getElementById('currentStatus').innerHTML = 'Logout from facebook Successfully.';
                        $window.location.reload();
                        $state.go("login");
                        //document.location.href='/';
                        /** Afer logout, Refresh the Page **/

                    });
                } else {
                    //                    document.location.href = '/login';
                    document.getElementById('currentStatus').innerHTML = 'You are NOT LOGIN in Facebook.';
                    console.log('You are not login in Facebook.')
                }
            });


        };
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk';
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                return;
            }
            js = d.createElement('script');
            js.id = id;
            js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));

    })
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-2 col-md-1" style="float:right">
                <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-log-out " style="margin-right:0px;color:white;font-size:20px;margin-top:10px;cursor:pointer" data-ng-show="$state.includes( 'chatPage') " ui-sref="logout "></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: define an angular route for the logout page and use it

Comment: I had defined but it is not working

Comment: You are calling `$window.location.reload();` twice before calling `$state.go("login")`

Comment: Actually that reload function is not working.That's Iam refreshing the page ang then only state is changing with logout successful